# Clojure: how to send remaining arguments "& args" into list?

Tags: function, clojure, macros, expand, args

Is there any (reasonable) way to write this macro as a function?

```
(defmacro assocTop
          [v & args]
          `(push (pop ~v)
                 (assoc (peek ~v) ~@args)))
```

Given a vector of maps and some associations, the macro code applies the associations to the top/peeked map.

However, when trying to write it as a function, I can't figure out how to expand the `~@args` in a legitimate way.  In normal functions, is there a way to turn `args`, which I believe has the form `(:a 3 :bb 44 :cd 90,...)` into `:a 3 :bb 44 :cd 90,...` ,i.e. without the parens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you should use [`apply`](http://www.clodoc.org/doc/clojure.core/apply) which will apply `assoc` to `(peek v)` and expanded `args`.

```
(defn assocTop
  [v & args]
  (push (pop v)
        (apply assoc (peek v) args)))
(=
  (assocTop [{:a :b} {:c :d} {:e :f, :g :h}] :e :z)
  [{:a :b} {:c :d} {:g :h, :e :z}]) ; => true
```

Comment: How come `reduce` doesn't work here but works with, say, `(defn push
[v & args] (reduce conj v args))`?

Comment: @spacingissue, I don't see how do you want to use `reduce` in this case. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I guess I was thinking that applying assoc repeatedly on the answer would be the same as reduce.  Is there a distinction to the `push` case (where you apply conj repeatedly on the answer)?